# Prove That$\frac{xy}{x^5+y^5+xy}+\frac{yz}{z^5+y^5+yz}+\frac{xz}{z^5+x^5+zx}\le 1$

Tags: inequality

If $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers and $xyz=1$, prove that

$$\frac{xy}{x^5+y^5+xy}+\frac{yz}{z^5+y^5+yz}+\frac{xz}{z^5+x^5+zx}\le 1$$

When does the equality hold?